# Listen to changes in TextField defined in FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am writing a simpe login GUI that is composed by a GridPane, which is the main container, then a TextField which takes in the user nickname and finally a login Button.

I wrote the GUI structure in FXML combined with CSS.

What I wanted to do was keeping the login Button disabled until the user actually wrote something in the TextField. I could only find an answer related to this but I wanted to know what was the best method to put this Listener in the FXML code itself so that I could get a cleaner code in the FXML controller.

I tried to use the method onKeyTyped but that didn't do the work cause I get no response whenever I'm typing in the TextField.

This is my FXML code

```
<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField"
           promptText="Username"
           onKeyTyped="#userTyped"
           stylesheets="@loginStyle.css">
```

What's the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, if you want to perform an action if the text of a text field changes, you need to register a listener with the text field's `textProperty()`, which you haver to do in the controller:

```
@FXML
private TextField usernameTextField ;

public void initialize() {
    usernameTextField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
        // do what you need with newText here, e.g.
        loginButton.setDisable(newText.isEmpty());
    });
}
```

However, if all you need is to bind a property in one control to a property in another control (or some simple dependency of that property), you can use [FXML expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding):

```xml
<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField"/>
<Button text="Login" disable="${usernameTextField.text.empty}" />
```

Here's a SSCCE:

`ButtonDisableTest.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="5" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <TextField fx:id="usernameTextField"/>
    <Button text="Login" disable="${usernameTextField.text.empty}" />
</VBox>
```

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonDisableTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ButtonDisableTest.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about FXML expression binding! Super helpful tip, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but if you want a listener for the TextField, you can do this without any code needed in `initialize()` through FXML.

Add the `onTextChange` attribute with a handler to your TextField:

```
<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField"
                   promptText="Username"
                   onTextChange="#userTyped">
```

in FXML then have a method in your controller:

```
public void userTyped(StringProperty property, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    // do stuff
}
```

(note that James_D's answer with expression binding would be cleaner if you only want to disable the button)

You can see [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#collections_and_property_handlers) for the official documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that your login Button have an fx:id="loginButton" and it is disabled

```
@FXML
public void userTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    loginButton.setDisable(false);
}
```

Comment: That would do the job, but I wanted something to be added directly to the FXML of the TextField

Comment: i don't think that it is possible to be done directly from the FXML

Comment: Also, this won't work in all cases: e.g. if the user copies and pastes text into the text field using the mouse, the key handler won't be invoked.